# Как заставить бота написать создателю?

Tags: python

У меня есть кнопка "Связаться с оператором", как мне сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на эту кнопку, то мне в Telegram писал бот и транслировал мои сообщения пользователю?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно в своём боте "зарегистрировать" этого оператора, либо список операторов. Для этого вынеси в любой файл, либо базу данных номер чата с оператором. А когда эта команда вызывается - считывай из файла или БД номер чата и туда шли сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Запускаешь бота у себя, пишешь event - когда приходит сообщение от пользователя {СВОЙНОМЕРТЕЛЕФОНА}, то оно копируется и отправляется пользователю.